# Converting Scanner to two ArrayLists, one with of Doubles and one of String

Tags: java

```
String dataSourceString = "String  43\n String1   50\n String2   45";
Scanner dataSource = new Scanner(dataSourceString);
ArrayList<String> scanString = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<Double> scanDoubleValue = new ArrayList<Double>();
while(dataSource.hasNextLine()) {
    scanString.add(dataSource.next());
    String stringToDouble = dataSource.next();
    Double doubleValue = stringToDouble.parseDouble();
    scanDoubleValue.add(doubleValue);
}
```

The ultimate goal is to convert a list of values of format `"String    Double"` to a treemap of `TreeMap<String, ArrayList<Double>> map = new TreeMap<>();`

I'm getting stuck on writing a loop to separate the two object types.

Comment: Why is the map value a list and not a double?

Comment: can you explain that what is key in your tree map and what is value in array list double. can you put some sample input and output/ contains of tree map. It will help to answer properly

Comment: How big do you expect the data source string to be in the worst case? If it's not too large, you could consider using String.split() instead of a scanner to parse the input.

Answer (score 0):

Why not write directly into a map, assuming value list is for duplicates

```
String dataSourceString = "String  43\n String1   50\n String2   45";
Scanner dataSource = new Scanner(dataSourceString);
ArrayList < String > scanString = new ArrayList < String > ();
ArrayList < Double > scanDoubleValue = new ArrayList < Double > ();
Map < String, List < Double >> map = new TreeMap <> ();
while (dataSource.hasNextLine()) {
    String key = dataSource.next();
    Double value = Double.parseDouble(dataSource.next());
    if (map.containsKey(key)) {
        map.get(key).add(value);
    } else {
        List < Double > valueList = new ArrayList();
        valueList.add(value);
        map.put(key, valueList);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.List;
import java.lang.Double;

public class DeleteFromList {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

   String dataSourceString = "String  43\n String1   50\n String2   45";
      Scanner dataSource = new Scanner(dataSourceString);
      ArrayList<String> scanString = new ArrayList<String>();
      ArrayList<Double> scanDoubleValue = new ArrayList<Double>();
      while(dataSource.hasNextLine()) {
          scanString.add(dataSource.next());
          String stringToDouble = dataSource.next();
          //your line hase the following and I changed it
          //Double doubleValue = stringToDouble.parseDouble();
          Double doubleValue = Double.parseDouble(stringToDouble);
          scanDoubleValue.add(doubleValue);
      }
      System.out.println(scanString);
      System.out.println(scanDoubleValue);
   }

}
```

Comment: Would be more helpful for OP to explain what you've changed and how that fixed his issue.

Comment: Didn't changed much. Just changed the line 'Double doubleValue = stringToDouble.parseDouble();'  to 'Double doubleValue = Double.parseDouble(stringToDouble);'. Check the edited code. Sorry, i didn't added changes.